# Issue while publish to azure 502.5 Error using Core 2.0.3

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have downloaded the latest Core SDK and installed it in my machine.
**Microsoft .Net Core SDK-2.0.3 (x64).**

I used the angular SPA template in VS2017 to create a new angular app and deploy no changes.
The app is running fine locally.

When I publish by this I am getting 502.5 Error.
On running 
dotnet xxx.dll in Console i am getting the following error.
Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (src.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'

As per this link
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542

I used the 2.0.0 nuget.
Local is working. When i try to publish to azure using azure publish
Getting this error.

Error
The command ""dotnet" exec --runtimeconfig "C:\DEBojyoti\Projects\TestWebApp\TestWebApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\TestWebApp.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "C:\DEBojyoti\Projects\TestWebApp\TestWebApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\TestWebApp.deps.json" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll" @"obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code 1.    TestWebApp      0

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Edit from Official [response from the ASP.NET Team](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542#issuecomment-346445287):

> The details for updating Linux servers running to run 2.0.3 are at
>   https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.3.md#linux.
>
> In short, you need to update the same components you installed to get
>   2.0.0 on to the box, whether it was the .NET Core SDK (apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.3), .NET Core runtime (apt-get install
>   dotnet-hosting-2.0.3), or manual TAR ball deployment.

---

I also got this error trying to run published my .NET Core 2.0 Web App on Linux after upgrading `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` to **2.0.3**. The solution was to revert back to **2.0.0** then redeploying.

Comment: But 2.0.3 fixes security issues... It would be great to be able to run the latest versions on azure..

Comment: @BlakeNiemyjski Yes it would be great minor NuGet package updates doesn't break deployment servers from hosting your App, but apparently that's not possible with the 2.0.3 update and we'll need to wait for an update that works.